# root ca not trusted - OCSP responder with nginx https server

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ocsp

For testing purposes I am trying to setup an https server, only for communication within a local network. TLS two way authentication and also OCSP stapling has to be used (due to the requirements of the client).

For nginx I have a basic setup:

```
listen 44300 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:44300 ssl default_server;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/work/Telematics2/server/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/work/Telematics2/server/certKey.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
    ssl_client_certificate /home/user/work/Telematics2/client/certificate.crt;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/work/Telematics2/server/concat.crt;
```

For testing I created server and client keys on my local machine with following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 1024

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key rootCA.key -out rootCA.crt -config validation.cnf -subj /C=DE/ST=BW/L=Earth/O=CompanyName/OU=IT/CN=X.X.X.X/emailAddress=email@example.com

openssl genrsa -out certKey.key 1024

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key certKey.key -out certificate.crt -config validation.cnf -subj /C=DE/ST=BW/L=Earth/O=CompanyName/OU=IT/CN=X.X.X.X/emailAddress=email@example.com

openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey certKey.key

openssl ca -batch -startdate 150813080000Z -enddate 250813090000Z -keyfile rootCA.key -cert rootCA.crt -policy policy_anything -config validation.cnf -notext -out certificate.crt -infiles CSR.csr

openssl req -new -nodes -out ocspSigning.csr -keyout ocspSigning.key -subj /C=DE/ST=BW/L=Earth/O=CompanyName/OU=IT/CN=X.X.X.X/emailAddress=email@example.com

yes | openssl ca -keyfile rootCA.key -cert rootCA.crt -in ocspSigning.csr -out ocspSigning.crt -config validation.cnf
```

The config contains following extra lines:

```
[ usr_cert ]
authorityInfoAccess = OCSP;URI:http://X.X.X.X:8080
[ v3_OCSP ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = OCSPSigning
```

I then started an OCSP server with openssl:

```
openssl ocsp -index demoCA/index.txt -port 8080 -rsigner ocspSigning.crt -rkey ocspSigning.key -CA rootCA.crt -text
```

and tried to access a simple html file on the server:

```
curl -v -L -k --cert /home/user/work/Telematics2/client/certificate.crt --key /home/user/work/Telematics2/client/certKey.key https://X.X.X.X:44300/index.html --cert-status --cacert /home/user/work/Telematics2/server/rootCA.crt
```

This gives me the following output:

```
*   Trying X.X.X.X...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to X.X.X.X (X.X.X.X) port 44300 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/user/work/Telematics2/server/rootCA.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=DE; ST=BW; L=Earth; O=CompanyName; OU=IT; CN=X.X.X.X; emailAddress=email@example.com
*  start date: Aug 13 08:00:00 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 13 09:00:00 2025 GMT
*  issuer: C=DE; ST=BW; L=Earth; O=CompanyName; OU=IT; CN=X.X.X.X; emailAddress=email@example.com
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* No OCSP response received
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS Unknown, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (91) No OCSP response received
```

and the nginx error.log says:

```
2020/02/19 14:53:04 [error] 29340#29340: OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:2706A067:OCSP routines:ocsp_check_delegated:missing ocspsigning usage error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted) while requesting certificate status, responder: X.X.X.X, peer: X.X.X.X:8080, certificate: "/home/user/work/Telematics2/server/certificate.crt"
```

But the above started ocsp server actually prints:

```
OCSP Response Data:
    OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
    Response Type: Basic OCSP Response
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Responder Id: C = DE, ST = BW, O = CompanyName, OU = IT, CN = X.X.X.X, emailAddress = email@example.com
    Produced At: Feb 19 14:17:18 2020 GMT
    Responses:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha1
      Issuer Name Hash: 3CFD1A620E876EB93992CA04B1903C354AC6C614
      Issuer Key Hash: 1E01DD83D567E3E111FD89E26B2636964C26AFDC
      Serial Number: 01
    Cert Status: good
    This Update: Feb 19 14:17:18 2020 GMT
```

I am not really an expert on this topic so I don't really know what to do next. I feel like the issue might be with the certificates, because it is the part I am most unsure about. I don't really need the security provided by OCSP but the client requires this step for a successful authentication, but it would be fine if I can just trust any CA if this is somehow possible.

Answer (score -2):

Probably because your ocspserver is running on localhost. Assuming you server from which youre trying to access the https url is not in the same machine Not sure.Trying to do a similar thing. Please let me know if i am wrong. or if you have  a solution